# How to Transfer data from JavaScript to Model using AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My implementation

**Model**

```
namespace Game.Models
{
    public class Lev_model
    {
        public static string GetJsonFile(string Level)
        {           
                string Data;
                string selectedLevel = "One";
                string one = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Data//lvl-one.json");
                string two = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/Data//lvl-two.json");
                if (selectedLevel == "One")
                {
                    Data = File.ReadAllText(one);
                }
                else if (selectedLevel == "Two")
                {
                    Data = File.ReadAllText(two);
                }
                else
                {
                    Data = "Default";
                }

                return Data;                      
        }        
    }
}
```

**View**

```
//AJAX call to change the selectedLevel to "one" or "two"


 var lvlData = "One"

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetLevelData", "Home")', 
            type: "POST",
        data: {strLvl: lvlData},
        success: function(response) {
            response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
        }
```

**Controller**

```
[RequireHttps]
        public ActionResult GetLevelData(string strLvl)
        {
            var data = Lev_model.GetJsonFile(strLvl);
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**My question**

How can I add a `View/ AJAX` call to change the value of my model. Notice that I hard code `selectedLevel to "One"` but I want to make it dynamic which means I can change the value so that it can load only one `JSON` file.

Comment: Are you trying to call the `GetJsonFile` method via ajax  ?

Comment: Where does the value come from? You simply need to add the `data: { strLvl: 'One; },` option to post back the value of `"One"` to your method (and remove the `contentType: "application/json",` option)

Comment: @Shyju I already converted the JSON to javascript Object, I just want to update the value of string selectedLevel in my model

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have a working example in my case? cause the url also returns an error, it's in my comment

Comment: Just noticed you have `var lvlData;` so its just `data { strLvl: lvlData },` and it will bind to the `string strLvl` parameter in the `GetLevelData()` method. What do you mean the url returns an error? - what error? (try `url: '@Url.Action("GetLevelData", "Home")',`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke do I need to add anything in my model?

Comment: You don't have a model. Still not sure what your error is with the url. It should be binding to the parameter fine (assuming you have removed `contentType: "application/json",`) and then its just a matter changing your `GetJsonFile()` method to `if (Level == "One")`

Comment: I'd updated my view, but still can't have the alert on sucess

Comment: You need to debug your code (and read my comments carefully)! The parameter name is `strLvl` but you passing it an object named `strSymbol` which wont match

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I already updated it but still cant have the success alert

Comment: Is the second parameter "Home" correct in the URL?

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you see some error message in debug console?

Comment: There is no error in debug but the value of selectedLevel in my model is not changing either

Comment: Can you hit "GetJsonFile" by attaching debugger? Or at least hit "GetLevelData"

Comment: Yes, but its returning null

Comment: I have removed [RequireHttps] and used this sample json 
{"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}
and I am getting data and alert "It worked" 

Something is missing in your code

Comment: maybe the URL is wrong

Comment: Could your problem be the fact that your controller action is ```get``` but your ajax call ```post```? [See what is default http verb](http://forums.asp.net/t/1928761.aspx?What+is+default+http+verb+for+action+method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/controller/GetLevelData',
            data : JSON.stringify({ 'strLvl': lvlData }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the issue? Is it showing any error on console?

Comment: There is no issue in console. Is there other ways ?

Comment: Is it hitting the controller?

Comment: It is returning null in the controller, which is probably due to URL error

Comment: Place `url: '/controller/GetLevelData?strLvl=' + lvlData` in place of url in `ajax` and comment out `data : JSON.stringify({ 'strLvl': lvlData })`

Comment: It's already having the alert, but my problem is that it is returning null in the controller

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: { strLvl: YourData},
        success: function (response) {
             //Do some thing
        },
        error: function () {
             //Error message
        }
    });
```